# Conditional parameters in Neural network using Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm interested in an architecture consists of two neural networks `NN1(), NN2()` such that

The outputs from first neural network `weights_for_NN2 = NN1(inputs1)` is the parameters/weights of second neural networks. Then the final outputs `outputs = NN2(inputs2)` will be used in a loss function `L = loss(outputs)`. So when we back propagate, we only need to update the weights of `NN1`

Now I just run a simple linear regression as toy; here is my code

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128,input_shape=(1,), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(2,input_shape=(128,))
])


class ConditionalModel(object):
    def __init__(self):

        self.W = tf.Variable([[5.0]],name="kernel")
        self.b = tf.Variable([0.0],name="bias")
        self.variables = [self.W,self.b]

    def __call__(self, x):
        return self.W * x + self.b

def loss(predicted_y, target_y):
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(predicted_y - target_y))

# do the training 
cond_model = ConditionalModel()
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=.1)
def train(model, inputs, outputs, learning_rate):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:

        param = model(tf.reshape(inputs,[-1,1]))
        w = tf.reduce_mean(param[:,:-1],axis=0)
        b = tf.reduce_mean(param[:,-1],axis=0)
        for var in cond_model.variables:
            if "kernel" in var.name:
                var.assign(tf.reshape(w,[1,1]))
            elif "bias" in var.name:
                var.assign(tf.reshape(b,[1,]))

    current_loss = loss(tf.squeeze(cond_model(tf.reshape(inputs,[-1,1]))), outputs)
    gradients = tape.gradient(current_loss, model.trainable_weights)
    print(gradients) # it prints [None,None,None,None] here
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_weights))
```

Here is a code for create some toy data

```
TRUE_W = 3.0
TRUE_b = 2.0
NUM_EXAMPLES = 1000

inputs  = tf.random.normal(shape=[NUM_EXAMPLES])
noise   = tf.random.normal(shape=[NUM_EXAMPLES])
outputs = inputs * TRUE_W + TRUE_b + noise
```

The above code doesn't work because `ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable` of my `NN1`. I believe is the way how do I assign value to my `NN2` causing the path to `NN1` computational graph broken. Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `W` and `b` directly solve the bug.

```py
for var in cond_model.variables:
    if "kernel" in var.name:
        cond_model.W = tf.reshape(w,[1,1])
    elif "bias" in var.name:
        cond_model.b = tf.reshape(b,[1])
```

Then you can get the gradient of `model.trainable_weights`.